# Summarizing a a simple $x$ term

Tags: real-analysis

How do I come from here: 
$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{a-2}{2} + 1$

To here
$\frac{1}{4}\cdot(a-2+4)$

When I calculate it I get
$\frac{1}{4} \cdot (a - 2) +1
=\frac{1}{4}\cdot a - \frac{2}{4} + 1
=\frac{1}{4}\cdot a - 0.5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just did at the last moment a simple mistake: $-\frac{2}{4}+1=+0.5$, not $-0.5$

If you correct this, you have the same result.